# luks - is there 2-factor authentication

Tags: security, luks, 2-factor-authentication

Is there anyway to achieve 2-factor authentication with luks so that if a key is compromised, if the other part is not in hand, the data is still secure?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, as shown [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu-two-factor-authentication-with-yubikey-for-harddisk-encryption-with-luks).

Comment: ok, after thinking about it, using a hardware key like yubikey is probably the best option - I was going to ask if I could use google authenticator (with my smartphone) to provide 2-factor.

Comment: I did look for a GA or similar solution, and came up dry.

Comment: @WalterWhite TOTP (as used by Google Authenticator) could not possibly work, because the key material would have to be available in the clear during the boot process so that it could be verified, but then an attacker can get their hands on it.